# Postgresql Service Takes Too Much Memory

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I have some issues with PostgreSQL. I've stopped all PostgreSQL user using

```
sudo pkil -9 -u postgres
```

and also stop all the daemon services related to Postgres.

But, suddenly the service reappear again in the background and takes memory. How to fix this ? what is the problem actually ?

I need help. I have no idea why this happened.
[image]

Regard,

Yogi

Comment: Do **not** use `kill` to shut down postgres, never. Stop the service using `service postgresql stop`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I did the way you told me. But the services keep coming back.